# Any way to force Chrome to cache PDFs automatically?

Tags: google-chrome

I open a lot of pdfs in my browser. This is often slow for me because chrome downloads them again every time I reopen chrome. Is there any way to force chrome to cache the pdfs automatically?

Comment: I suspect not, even though it does seem to cache, after download, so it might be possible. HOWEVER to load a PDF (not always but in general) requires a full load of the PDF into the extended PDFium reader. So why not simply use a proper High Speed external reader with ability to remember last opened tabs, from the Hard Disk Cafe